# How to set the room availability to False after I selected a room in django

Tags: python, django

Im currently developing a Hotel Management System and I would like to set the availability of room to False after i choose it on reservations form.

Here is my codes :

**models.py**

```
class Room(models.Model):
    room = (
        ('Standard Room' , 'Standard Room'),
        ('Deluxe Room', 'Deluxe Room'),
        ('VIP Room', 'VIP Room')
    )
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    room_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=room , verbose_name = 'Type of Room')
    room_no = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name = 'Room No', unique=True, help_text = "Should be unique and not existing room no")
    rates = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, verbose_name = "Rates per Room")
    available = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Available")


    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.room_type}" + " | " + "Room " + f"{self.room_no}"

class Reservations(models.Model):
    room = (
        ('Standard Room' , 'Standard Room'),
        ('Deluxe Room', 'Deluxe Room'),
        ('VIP Room', 'VIP Room')
    )
    customer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name="reservation_user" )
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255, verbose_name = 'Customer Name')
    address = models.CharField(max_length = 255, verbose_name = 'Address')
    email_address = models.EmailField(verbose_name = 'Email Address')
    contact = models.CharField(max_length = 255, verbose_name = 'Contact No')
    type_of_id = models.CharField(max_length = 255, verbose_name = 'Type of ID')
    id_no = models.CharField(max_length = 255, verbose_name = 'ID No')
    no_of_days = models.CharField(max_length = 255, verbose_name = 'No of Days')
    check_in_datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, verbose_name = "Date & Time for Check In")
    check_out_datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, verbose_name = "Date & Time for Check Out")
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete = models.SET_NULL,null=True,related_name="room_type_and_no", verbose_name = "Room Type & No" )
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.customer}"

    def no_of_hrs(self):
        return self.check_in_datetime - self.check_out_datetime
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def create_reservations(request):
    """ This is where we render the forms for creating new reservations """
    
    template_name = "reservations/create_reservations.html"
    
    form = ReservationForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        reserved = form.save(commit=False)
        reserved.customer = request.user
        reserved.save()
        messages.success(request, "You have successfully create a new reservations")
        return redirect('reservations:reservations_pre_list')
    else:
        form = ReservationForm(request.POST or None)

    context = {
        'form' : form
    }

    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

**forms.py**

```
class ReservationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    class Meta :
        model = Reservations
        fields = ['name','address','email_address','contact','type_of_id','id_no','no_of_days','check_in_datetime', 'check_out_datetime']
        widgets = {
            'check_in_datetime' : TimeInput(),
            'check_out_datetime' : TimeInput(),

        }
```

So how to set the room availability to false after i choose it ? For example, if I reserved the room 101, It will not going to show up again in the room choices.

Comment: Can you post your `ReservationForm`? (Do you collect which `Room` the user wants?)

Comment: @etnguyen03 hello sir I edit the post and I include the ReservationForm